# Error on next-18next integration with latest nextjs: appWithTranslation was called without a next-i18next config

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, next.js, i18next, next-i18next

I am upgrading today app to latest nextjs version (10.0.9).

In order to move translates I used [next-i18next](https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next) lib and its simple example from Github.

However, in my app I always get next error:
[image]

On debugger of next-i18next lib, I found that this error thrown in case of i18n config does not provided.

In my app configurations looks like:

nextjs.config.js [image: nextjs.config.js]

next-i18next.config.js
[image]

_app.js

```
const HeadstartApp = (props) => {
const { Component, apollo, redux, theme } = props;
  const reduxRef = useRef(initRedux(redux));
  const apolloRef = useRef(
    getApolloClient()
  );
return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Head>
        <title>Example</title>
        <meta
          name='viewport'
          content='minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, width=device-width'
        />
      </Head>
     
      <ApolloProvider client={apolloRef.current}>
        <Provider store={reduxRef.current}>
          <div dir={locale === 'he' ? 'rtl' : 'ltr'}>
            <ThemeProvider theme={createMuiTheme(theme)}>
              {/* <AppBar position={'static'}>
            <Toolbar>
              <Typography>
                <h1>{locale}</h1>
              </Typography>
              <Link href='/projects/construction/1'>
                <Button>Project 1</Button>
              </Link>
              <Link href='/projects/digital/2'>
                <Button>Project 2</Button>
              </Link>
            </Toolbar>
          </AppBar> */}

              <Layout {...props}>
                <Component {...props} />
              </Layout>
            </ThemeProvider>
          </div>
        </Provider>
      </ApolloProvider>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
    }
export default appWithTranslation(HeadstartApp);
```

index.js

```
const HomePage = (props) => {
...code
}

export const getStaticProps = async ({ locale, defaultLocale }) => ({
  props: {
    ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale || defaultLocale, [
      'common',
      'homepage',
    ])),
  },
});

export default HomePage;
```

It looks like my app has same configurations as simple example [here](https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next/tree/master/examples/simple), but throws this strange exception.
Someone got something and can help to solve it

Comment: Please add all your code as snippets, do not use images for code.

Comment: Make sure your config files have the correct names (`next.config.js` & `next-i18next.config.js`) and are both located in the root folder.

Answer (score 3):

That's the solution that works for me:

- In the `_app.js` import import `i18next.config`, like this `import NextI18nextConfig from '../../next-i18next.config'`, this will guarantee that you are loading the configurations.
- Then exported it in the `appWithTranslation`, like this `export default appWithTranslation(App, NextI18nextConfig)`

This will override the default config.